# win python3 Multithreading

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, multithreading

Very strange thing, changing the order in which thread code is created will have different results.

There are two threads, I want them to be Concurrently executed. No matter what I do there only one thread is working.
And the order I create thead change the result.

```
from socket import *
from time import *
from threading import Thread
udpsocket=None#套接字
destIp=''
destPort=0
#收数据
def recvData():
    global udpsocket, destIp, destPort
    while(True):
        mytime = asctime(localtime())
        recvInfo=udpsocket.recvfrom(1024)
        data,info=recvInfo
        print(">>[%s] %s:%s" % (mytime, info[0],data.decode("gb2312")))
#发数据
def sendData():
    global udpsocket, destIp, destPort
    while(True):
        sendinfo=input("<<")
        udpsocket.sendto(sendinfo.encode("gb2312"),(destIp,destPort))
def main():
    global udpsocket,destIp,destPort
    destIp=input("ip:")
    destPort=int(input("port:"))
    udpsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    udpsocket.bind(("",4567))
    #change order
    ThreadRecv = Thread(target=recvData())
    ThreadSend = Thread(target=sendData())
    ##
    ThreadSend.start()
    ThreadRecv.start()
    ThreadSend.join()
    ThreadRecv.join()
    udpsocket.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want the sendData and recvData to be Concurrently executed. By the way I use NetAssist be another client. In one OS.

Answer (score 2):

first look and I think you should pass only the name of a target to the Thread class, not execute the function. 
If you run like this:

```
ThreadRecv = Thread(target=recvData())
```

you pass to the Thread result of a recvData() execution.

You only want to pass the name (address) of a function in a constructor so try this:

```
ThreadRecv = Thread(target=recvData) #without braces 
ThreadSend = Thread(target=sendData) #without braces
```

If you do it with braces, the instance of Thread is created and in **init**() (or even sooner) of Thread your recvData is executed and runs the endless loop, so the Thread object init is not really finished and you run only one of the functions(the first one).

Try without the braces.

Cheers

Comment: WOW! Thank you! Love you~~~